# What is the exact proof that Busy Beaver function grows asymptotically faster than any computable function?

Tags: proof-explanation, computational-complexity, computability

I have seen the following formulation of the proof:

> If there is a computable function $\forall n\ge n_0:f(n) \ge BB(n)$ then $f(n)$ can be used as an upper bound for $BB(n)$, thus making it computable, which is a contradiction.

However, this is only possible if you know such $f(n)$ exactly. Suppose there is a set $S$ of all computable functions $f(n)$ such that $\forall n\ge n_0:f(n) \ge BB(n)$. The question is, how can one prove $S=\varnothing$?

Notice that so far just an existence of $f(n)\in S$ does not allow to compute $BB(n)$ - you need to also have a procedure that verifies if $f(n)\in S$ in a finite time. Considering that $BB(n)$ is undecidable, no such procedure exists, of course. It seems pretty similar to games where it is known that a winning strategy exists, but finding such a strategy is uncomputable.

None of that seems to be sufficient to prove $S=\varnothing$. Is there something I am missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Scott Aaronson's survey paper on the Busy Beaver function](https://scottaaronson.com/bb.pdf) includes this proposition, which I think is responsive to your question:

> **Proposition 3:** Let $f : \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$ be any computable function. Then there exists an $n_f$ such that $BB(n)>f(n)$ for all $n\ge n_f$.

> **Proof:** Let $M_f$ be a Turing machine that computes $f(n)$, for any $n$ encoded on $M_f$'s input tape. Suppose $M_f$ has $c$ states. Then for all $n$, there exists a Turing machine $M_{f,n}$ with $c + O (\log n)$ states that, given an all-$0$ input tape, first writes $n$ onto the input tape, then simulates $M_f$ in order to compute $f(n)$, and finally executes an empty loop for (say) $f(n)^2$ steps. Hence
> $$BB (c + O (\log n)) > f (n)$$
> for all $n$ from which the proposition follows.

Comment: Hm, but can a function like $TREE(n)$ be computed with the same finite constant amount of states for every $n$? I guess there is a class of non-uniformly computable functions.

Comment: Any computable function can be computed by a single Turing machine regardless of the value of $n$ -- this is pretty much the definition of "computable function".

Comment: I suppose the bound can be tightened to $BB(c + BB^{-1}(n) + k)>f(n)$, where $BB^{-1}(n)$ is a function that returns the lowest amount of states that a TM that outputs a number $n_0\ge n$ must have. $k$ since not all functions are monotonic.